# F# constructor doesn't accept tuples?

Tags: f#, constructor, tuples

I tried to use a tuple to create a new instance of a class defined in F#. To duplicate the problem, I tried the following code.

```
type test(x: int, y:int) =
    let distance =
        x * x + y * y |> float |> sqrt
    new (x: int, y:int, z:int) =
        new test(x, y)
let args = 1, 2
let test2 = new test(args)
```

It complains that

> Error 1   The member or object
>   constructor 'test' does not take 1
>   argument(s). An overload was found
>   taking 2 arguments.

If I remove the non-default constructor, things are fine.
I don't understand why it becomes two/three arguments instead of tuples.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is subtle, but per the spec.  Here's an old email response I dug up where someone asked a similar question:

...

At play, there is also (subtle) difference between "tuples" (in the F# language) and "syntactic tuples" (in the F# specification).

Method application resolution is different when there are overloads. If there are none, the decomposition of the argument (i.e. the "stuff" specified between ( and ) in your method invocation) to a tuple form does not happen, so the compiler is happy and say "oh ok, the ctor for MyClass takes 1 argument (a tuple) and I am seeing 1 argument ("tuple" in  your code) so I’ll use that".

Whereas, when you have 2 overloads, then the rule above does not apply anymore and the compiler will try to decompose the argument to a tuple form (which in your case would resolve in something like: "Oh ok, there is 1 argument which is tuple. But wait, I have 2 overloads. And your list of argument (one element, tuple) does not match either an argument list, hence the error message"

At least, that’s my interpretation of the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html), section 14.4.

Comment: I wasn't surprised that the compiler doesn't treat constructor argument as a tuple in this case, but I was quite surprised that you cannot use patterns in the constructor binding i.e. `type Test( (x, y) ) = ...` (or any other patterns). Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Thanks a lot. F# is really confusing in some aspects.

Comment: I was the one who asked via email; glad I'm not the only one who found this confusing! You'll also get the same problem using method overloading (the constructor is treated like a method).

Comment: @Brian - I suppose it might be because constructor arguments become fields, in this case, so it is worth to be more explicit about how they are defined. But still, it doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 5):

There may be an easier syntax to get this working, but I don't know what it is:

```
type Test(tup : int*int) =
    let x, y = tup
    let distance =
        x * x + y * y |> float |> sqrt
    new (tup : int*int*int) =
        let x, y, _ = tup
        new Test((x, y))

let args1 = 1, 2
let test1 = new Test(args1)

let args2 = 3, 4, 5
let test2 = new Test(args2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I had thought that multiple arguments in a pair of parenthesis are the same as tuples.